# Run PHPUnit by terminal with Docker

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

#### What I want

I have project, where don't have docker/docker-compose.
I want run PHP scripts - PHPUnit by terminal. Best would be working with PhpStorm.

## What I have

#### File *docker-phpez*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# echo "Current working directory: '"$(pwd)"'"
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/var/www -e SYMFONY_ENV=dev ezsystems/php:7.1-v1 php $@
```

## Result

#### Checking version

Run this `docker-phpez -v`, give me:

```
PHP 7.1.6 (cli) (built: Jun 12 2017 21:35:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.6, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with blackfire v1.17.1~linux-x64-non_zts71, https://blackfire.io, by SensioLabs
```

Then this is correct.

#### Checking mount

When I run listing (modify files) then, I see all needed files.

#### Run PHPUnit

When I try to run, it see config file in main folder, but won't see bootstrap file in path:

```
PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/src/Tests/../../vendor/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/src/Tests/bootstrap.php on line 3
```

Question:

- why PHP inside container don't see this file, when I see this running inside `ls /var/www/src/Tests` ?

## Update v1:

#### running pwd

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/var/www -e SYMFONY_ENV=dev ezsystems/php:7.1-v1 pwd
```

give:

```
/var/www
```

#### running ls

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/var/www -e SYMFONY_ENV=dev ezsystems/php:7.1-v1 ls
```

give list of all files/folders in current folder.

#### Composer

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/var/www -e SYMFONY_ENV=dev ezsystems/php:7.1-v1 composer install
```

run correctly and install all data.

## All command are run in MAIN folder of project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
/var/www/src/Tests/../../vendor/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/config.php
```

is translated to:

```
/var/www/vendor/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/config.php
```

Because of `../..`

You are not looking there.

Comment: ok, do you know, how to add that php should see main catalog? and needed file would be visible?

Comment: It depends on where you have put the vendor and maybe the rest of the app. Also check whether you are running the tests from the wrong working directory.

Comment: So, do you have this `/var/www/vendor/`?

Comment: yes, running `run --rm -v $(pwd):/var/www -e SYMFONY_ENV=dev ezsystems/php:7.1-v1 ls vendor/` or `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/var/www -e SYMFONY_ENV=dev ezsystems/php:7.1-v1 ls /var/www/vendor` give same result - content of vendor from localmachine.

Comment: find out, that problem was not configuration itselt, but vendor + composer had bug. My mistake - i'm blind.

The file wasn't creating as it should.
thanks for efford.

Comment: Ok, nice so :) !