# PhpStorm doesn't read PHP configuration from Docker container

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

## What I want

Run PHPUnit by terminal and configuration in PhpStorm

## What I Have

#### Previous problem

[Resolved in HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823973/run-phpunit-by-terminal-with-docker) - about not finding files

#### File that running

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# echo "Current working directory: '"$(pwd)"'"
cd $(pwd) && docker run --rm -t -v $(pwd):/var/www -e SYMFONY_ENV=dev ezsystems/php:7.1-v1-dev php $@
```

## Summary

When I run this by terminal:

```
docker-phpez vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text
```

Everything working correctly.

When I try to run this with configuration of PhpStorm, I get warning that: `PHP is not installed`.

But running this as remote PHP interpreter, gives me:

```
docker://ezsystems/php:7.1-v1/php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --configuration /var/www/phpunit.xml.dist
Testing started at 17:06 ...
The value $_SERVER['IDE_PHPUNIT_PHPUNIT_PHAR'] is specified, but file doesn't exist '/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Looking like mounting doesn't work.

Question:

- do you know why? How to fix that?

In previous version of PhpStorm I didn't had any problem with that.
Right now, I have 2016.3.2.

Comment: Try newer IDE versions (just in case) -- stable 2017.1.4 and EAP build of 2017.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating PHPStorm to 2017.1.4, what I did:

- switched to docker configuration
- phpunit loaded from composer's autoload.php

Started to working. Still don't know why `docker-phpez` not working by PHPStorm, but I will stop for now.

Answer (score 1):

Because after update you have to update tags for `phpstorm_helpers` docker image. There i put more how it should be fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189164